# CollectionViewSource for a single item WPF

Tags: wpf, prism, collectionviewsource

I have an MVVM application where I am assigning a single String value to a CollectionViewSource and binding it in the view to a label. The string value is coming from database using Entity Framework. Whenever the string changes in the database I want to update the value of the label. But CollectionViewSource is working fine with List or any collection but when I do the same for a single string i.e when I assign string to CollectionViewSource and bind it to the label it displays "MS.Internal.Data.Enumerable.Collection". 
How do I assign a single value to CollectionViewSource..Please help.

Comment: Do you really need the `CollectionViewSource`?

Comment: Yes I need to update the Label on the view whenever the database changes onclick of a button. Even the SetProperty (Bindable Base) for the string is updating but not reflecting the change to the view. So I need something like a collectionviewsource.

Comment: OK, if you want to set your `Label`'s text to a string (whatever it comes from - database or user input), you certainly don't need a `CollectionViewSource`. Create a `string` property in your view model, fire a `PropertyChanged` event on that property changes and bind your `Label`'s content to that property.

Comment: Oh sorry I was doing it wrong..It worked. Sorry I didnt check properly. The Bindable Base works exactly fine.